# Missing solution of $\frac{d^2 u}{ds^2} + \frac{1}{u}\left(1 - \left(\frac{du}{ds} \right)^2\right) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$  \frac{d^2 u}{ds^2} + \frac{1}{u}\left(1 -  \left(\frac{du}{ds} \right)^2\right)  = 0$$

Clearly $u(s) = s$ is a particular solution to this equation, and in fact the one I seek. (This arose from trying to find geodesics of the metric $ds^2 = du^2 + \frac{dv^2}{u^2}$). However, the solution I get is
$$u(s) = \pm \frac{\sinh \left( c_1 s + c_2\right)}{c_1}$$
Where did I lose the solution $u(s) = s$. Or Did I not lose it at all?

**My Solution Attempt**
$$  \frac{d^2 u}{ds^2} + \frac{1}{u}\left(1 -  \left(\frac{du}{ds} \right)^2\right)  = 0$$
Let $w(u) = \frac{du}{ds}$. This gives that $\frac{d^2 u}{ds^2} = w(u) \frac{dw}{du}$. We have
$$w(u) \frac{dw}{du} + \frac{1}{u}(1 - w(u)^2) = 0 $$
Separating variables gives
$$\frac{w}{w^2 -1} dw = \frac{du}{u} $$
Let $\xi = w^2 - 1$. Hence $d \xi = 2w dw$ and 
$$\frac{d \xi}{2 \xi} = \frac{du}{u} $$
Integrating gives 
$$ \xi = c_1 u^2 $$
In more familiar terms we have
$$\left(\frac{du}{ds}\right)^2 - 1 = c_1 u^2$$
Separating variables once and integrating gives 
$$\pm \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 + c_1u^2}} = \int ds $$
Let $\sinh \phi = \sqrt{c_1}  u$. This transforms the integral into 
$$\pm  \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1}} \int \frac{\cosh \phi d \phi}{\sqrt{1 - \sinh^2 \phi}} = s + c_2$$
$$\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1}} \phi = s + c_2 $$
$$\pm \text{arcsinh} \> \sqrt{c_1} u = \sqrt{c_1} s + c_2$$
$$u(s) = \pm \frac{\sinh \left( c_1 s + c_2\right)}{c_1}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{\sinh(c_1 x+c_2)}{c_1}\to x$ as $c_2\to 0,c_1\to 0$ (taken in that order).

Comment: You lost $u(s)=s$ when you decided to divide by $\xi$, which assumes $\xi\ne0$, that is, $w^2\ne1$. To get the solution $u(s)=s$ from your last formula, choose $\pm=+$, $c_2=0$ and consider the limit when $c_1\to0$. (Unrelatedly, you forgot tons of other solutions, for example those such that the first $c_1$ is negative.)

Comment: Ah of course! Is there a better approach to solving this ODE such that we don't lose tons of solutions like I did?